# Where should I load programs into RAM?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am developing an operating system in assembly. I have got a working executable loader that loads COM files but I am not sure were I should load them. My OS is loaded into RAM at 0x200000. At the moment I have no memory management or anything like that. I am just scared that I will load a program into somewere were I shouldn't (Like into video ram , or overwrite existing code). Does the bios use anything before 0x200000 besides the IDT and the video RAM.

Comment: That is an incredibly vague question. I kinda doubt you will get useful answers like this.

Comment: Yes I agree , i'll add more details

Comment: still more detail.  I assume this is x86?  what operating system or other environment are you trying to load with/into?  as far as peripherals (video card) the bios enumerates the pci(e) bus(es) and places those things in memory, dos and linux and other tools will show you where those are placed, not necessarily the same every boot but the bios uses the same range every time (unless you tell it otherwise) usually a 1gig window for 32 bit machines in the upper 3rd or 4th gig, 64 bit might have a 2 gig window

Comment: I am writing an OS from complete scratch , it uses syslinux as its bootloader. It is 32 bit and in protected mode. And yeah it is for x86 processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be safe with almost anything above 0x100000. I load my kernel to that address, and you can store programs in most of your upper memory.

You should have plenty of space above 0x100000 for the OS and programs. Some sections before that are usable, but it may be easier to avoid that part unless you really need it.

[Memory Map (x86) - OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29) is a great reference for some of the things you can expect.

[Detecting Memory (x86) - OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29) explains how to find available memory.

Comment: -1. There can be memory-mapped devices above 1MB mark. You should really check out the BIOS functions that return you the layout of the RAM.